How do I get current view from a blend file without a camera?
This is what I see after loading a blend file, which is without a camera:

And I hope to export this object to a ply file for my hobby renderer (this part it works), but I couldn't find any way to get current view parameters (particularly I need 3 vectors: position, up, lookat). Is there a way to find these parameters?

You want to view it from the top? Press Numpad 7?

@HarryMcKenzie, no I mean the camera parameters of current view port

Getting the viewport params

@GordonBrinkmann oh via python. i was thinking from the UI. my bad.

Hi Rahn I have closed it as duplicate question, let me know if that is not what you were looking for and I will reopen your question.
